# only show blog-entries of specific categories on my page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

Excluding "uncategorized" i've got three categories: 'News', 'E1', 'E2'
I also got two pages (E1, E2) with the same blog-template. The plan is, to show  on each page all entries of 'News' and all of the fitting 'E*'-category. How would I do this?
The Theme I'm using ist Attitude-Free from Theme-Horse.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog Full Content Display
 *
 * Displays the Blog with Full Content Display.
 *
 * @package Theme Horse
 * @subpackage Attitude
 * @since Attitude 1.0
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>



<?php $args = array(
         'posts_per_page'   => 5,
         'offset'           => 0,
         'category'         => 'E1',
         'orderby'          => 'post_date',
         'order'            => 'DESC',
         'include'          => '',
         'exclude'          => '',
         'meta_key'         => '',
         'meta_value'       => '',
         'post_type'        => 'post',
         'post_mime_type'   => '',
         'post_parent'      => '',
         'post_status'      => 'publish',
         'suppress_filters' => true ); 

 $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>



<?php
/** 
 * attitude_before_main_container hook
     */
    do_action( 'attitude_before_main_container' );
?>
<?php
/**
 * Überschrift
 *
 * bla
 */
?>
<h3>Content:</h3>

<div id="container">
<?php
    /** 
     * attitude_main_container hook
     *
     * HOOKED_FUNCTION_NAME PRIORITY
     *
     * attitude_content 10
         */
        do_action( 'attitude_main_container' );
    ?>
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php
    /** 
     * attitude_after_main_container hook
     */
    do_action( 'attitude_after_main_container' );
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your question is very different from the original, however, this is all you have in your page?

Comment: sadly yes, i quess its because of the theme I'm using. there is allmost no code inside each *.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all posts of a category, you can use get_posts() wordpress function.

For example

```
<?php $args = array(
         'posts_per_page'   => 5,
         'offset'           => 0,
         'category'         => 'E1',
         'orderby'          => 'post_date',
         'order'            => 'DESC',
         'include'          => '',
         'exclude'          => '',
         'meta_key'         => '',
         'meta_value'       => '',
         'post_type'        => 'post',
         'post_mime_type'   => '',
         'post_parent'      => '',
         'post_status'      => 'publish',
         'suppress_filters' => true ); 

 $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Then you only have to loop into this array, and show them as you want.

If you want more information, this is the [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: I integrated this code beneath the "get_header()" function, but nothing happens. above the template as it looks now.

Comment: Try <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($posts_array); echo '</pre>'; ?>

Comment: before or after the snippet?

Comment: After the snippet. These code only will show you what information is in the array. You have to loop it.

Comment: now something happened, but not as expected http://svs03.azurewebsites.net/?page_id=331

Comment: Now you have the data, you only has to loop through it and show it as you want. If you have another template, copy the code inside the "have_post()" loop, and change whatever it's necessary to make it work.

Comment: I appreciate for your help and realy dont want to bother you, but i'm bloody new to php and do not realy know how i should do this.